# Деструктор вызывается раньше, чем надо

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class forlab
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int size;
    int* arr;
    forlab(std::string name, int size) {
        this->size = size;
        this->name = name;
        *&arr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    forlab() {
        this->name = "";
        this->size = 0;
        this->arr = 0;
    }
    ~forlab() {
        delete [] this->arr;
    }
    int& operator[] (const int index);
    friend forlab operator+(const forlab a,const forlab b);
    void show() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << this->arr[i] << " ";
        }
    }
};

int& forlab::operator[] (const int index)
{
    return this->arr[index];
}
forlab operator+(const forlab a, const forlab b) {
    forlab temp("", a.size+b.size);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size; i++) {
        temp.arr[i] = a.arr[i];
    }
    int counter = a.size;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size; i++) {
        temp.arr[counter] = b.arr[i];
        counter++;
    }
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    forlab ex1("first", 15);
    forlab ex2("second", 20);
    forlab ex3 = ex1 + ex2;
    ex3.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Деструктор вызывается раньше окончания программы из-за этого числа из динамического массива хранящегося в экземпляре ex3 не выводятся, а программа в деструкторе ловит исключение

Comment: `*&arr = new int[size];` - странная конструкция

Comment: по условию задания, надо в качестве поля указать адрес в памяти для динамического массива, а в конструкторе уже инициализировать его

Comment: Ну а где `operator=` и `forlab(const forlab&)`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Answer (score 2):

Когда `operator+` завершается, `temp` уничтожается и в `ex3` помещается **копия** `temp`. Но в копии хранится ссылка на массив `arr`, который освободился при вызове деструктора. Получается, что `arr` в `ex3` - висячий указатель. Чтобы этого избежать, можно перегрузить [конструктор копирования](https://ravesli.com/urok-141-konstruktor-kopirovaniya/):

```cpp
forlab(const forlab& f) {
    size = f.size;
    name = f.name;
    arr = new int[size];                    // заново выделяем память
    memcpy(arr, f.arr, sizeof(int) * size); // копируем весь массив
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло

Comment: @Topinambur почему? У меня всё работает. https://onlinegdb.com/HkWNToT4Sv

Answer (score 1):

У вас программа просто падает из-за двойного освобождения памяти в деструкторе - у вас нет копирующего конструктора, вот и получается, что копируется указатель (поверхностное копирование, генерируемое компилятором), а не память...

Допишите конструктор копирования, примерно такой

```
forlab(const forlab& f):name(f.name),size(f.size)
{
    arr = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = f.arr[i];
    }
}
```

и все встанет на свои места...

P.S. А, ну да, еще и оператор присваивания, само собой... Но в данном случае он не то чтобы не нужен - просто он нигде не вызывается.

А чтобы убедиться - давайте допишем вывод в конструкторах-деструкторах:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class forlab
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int size;
    int* arr;
    forlab(std::string name, int size) {

        cout << "Ctor " << name << endl;

        this->size = size;
        this->name = name;
        *&arr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    forlab() {
        cout << "Default ctor\n";
        this->name = "";
        this->size = 0;
        this->arr = 0;
    }
    forlab(const forlab& f):name(f.name),size(f.size)
    {

        cout << "Copy ctor " << name << endl;

        arr = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            arr[i] = f.arr[i];
        }
    }
    ~forlab() {
        cout << "Dtor " << name << endl;

        delete [] this->arr;
    }

    int& operator[] (const int index);
    friend forlab operator+(const forlab a,const forlab b);
    void show() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cout << this->arr[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int& forlab::operator[] (const int index)
{
    return this->arr[index];
}
forlab operator+(const forlab a, const forlab b) {
    forlab temp("", a.size+b.size);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size; i++) {
        temp.arr[i] = a.arr[i];
    }
    int counter = a.size;
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size; i++) {
        temp.arr[counter] = b.arr[i];
        counter++;
    }
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    forlab ex1("first", 15);
    forlab ex2("second", 20);
    forlab ex3 = ex1 + ex2;
    ex3.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Скомпилируйте, запустите, убедитесь в соответствии конструкторов деструкторам:

```
Ctor first
Ctor second
Copy ctor second
Copy ctor first
Ctor 
Dtor first
Dtor second
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Dtor 
Dtor second
Dtor first
```

Посмотрите, например, [тут](https://ideone.com/3eV9YS). Теперь помогло?

Кстати, если вы замените

```
forlab operator+(const forlab a, const forlab b) {
```

на

```
forlab operator+(const forlab & a, const forlab & b) {
```

то избежите двух лишних копирований. Попробуйте сами..

Comment: Дополнил ответ, написал полностью код. У вас такой же? В таком случае - **где** он у вас не работает?.. Да, глобально надо еще и оператор присваивания - просто в вашем коде присваивания нигде не было, вот я его и не вспоминал.